# How can I view the log of cloudwatch rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I create a rule in `cloudwatch` to trigger a lambda function when a `glue job` state is changed. The rule patterned is defined:

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "Glue Job State Change"
  ],
  "source": [
    "aws.glue"
  ]
}
```

In `Show metrics for the rule` view I can see that there is one `FailedInvocation` but I can't find a way to see why the invocation is failed. I have checked the lambda function log but it is not being called. So how can I view the log of the failed invocation?